# How to I get validation error messages with Multisheets in Laravel-excel

Tags: php, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I'm following [this](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/multiple-sheets.html#multiple-sheets) example from the docs to handle multiple sheets import.

My Controller:

```
    public function import(Request $request) {
    
        $file = $request->file('import')->store('/storage');
        $import = new MultisheetContactsImport();        
        $import->import($file);            
    
   
        if ($import->failures()->isNotEmpty()) {
            return $import->failures();
        } 

        return $import->getRowCount();           
    }
```

My import class ContactsImport.php

```
namespace App\Imports;

use App\Models\Email;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\withHeadingRow;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\SkipsOnError;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\SkipsErrors;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Importable;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithValidation;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\SkipsOnFailure;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\SkipsFailures;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToCollection;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Throwable;
class ContactsImport implements ToModel, withHeadingRow, SkipsOnError, WithValidation, SkipsOnFailure
{      
    private $rows = 0;

    use Importable, SkipsErrors, SkipsFailures;    

    /**
    * @param array $row
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
    */
    public function model(array $row)
    {
    ++$this->rows;

    return new Email([
        'apiKey' => Str::random(16),
        'firstname' => $row['firstname'],
        'lastname' => $row['lastname'],
        'emailAddress' => $row['emailaddress'],
        'businessType' => $row['businesstype'],
        'allowed' => true,
        'updates' => true,
        'marketing' => true,
    ]);       
    }

    public function getRowCount(): int
    {
        return $this->rows;
    }    

    public function rules(): array 
    {
        return [
            '*.emailaddress' => ['email', 'unique:emails,emailaddress']
        ];
    }     
}
```

My Multisheet import class MultisheetContactsImport.php

```
class MultisheetContactsImport extends ContactsImport implements WithMultipleSheets
{  
    public function sheets(): array
    {
        return [
            'Contacts' => new ContactsImport()
        ];       
    }    
}
```

The methods failures and and getRowCount work fine if I use the ContactsImport class without multisheets however now I only get a response 0

Answer (score 2):

Just Wrap your import line code with try catch block it should handle every thing:

```
     try {
        $master = Excel::import(new MasterImport($auth), $request->file('master_upload'));
    } catch (\Maatwebsite\Excel\Validators\ValidationException $e) {
        $failures = $e->failures();
        dd($failures);
         
         foreach ($failures as $failure) {
             $failure->row(); // row that went wrong
             $failure->attribute(); // either heading key (if using heading row concern) or column index
             $failure->errors(); // Actual error messages from Laravel validator
             $failure->values(); // The values of the row that has failed.
         }
    }
```

Comment: Nice! I'll give it a try and see. Thank you! I decided to take another route, I'll post the updated code later

Comment: Is there a way to display the Sheet Name in which the validation failed?

Answer (score 0):

You can add this method on you ImportClass

```
/**
 * @param Failure ...$failures
 * @throws ValidationException
 */
public function onFailure(Failure ...$failures)
{
    $exception = ValidationException::withMessages(collect($failures)->map->toArray()->all());

    throw $exception;
}
```

User Laravel Validation Exeption

```
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;
```

and than on the view display validation messages:

```
@if(count($errors->getMessages()) > 0)
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
    <strong>Validation Errors:</strong>
    <ul>
        @foreach($errors->getMessages() as $errorMessages)
            @foreach($errorMessages as $errorMessage)
                <li>
                    {{ $errorMessage }}
                    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
                </li>
            @endforeach
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</div>@endif
```